Can I use a single DynamoDB table for state locking in multiple terraform projects?
I currently have multiple projects and I’m using one S3 bucket for my state backend . These multiple project state files are separated by paths in the S3 bucket. Now, I want to implement DynamoDB state file lock. Since I have multiple projects, can I use only one DynamoDB table, like I used one S3 bucket for my state file backend? If the answer is yes, how does DynamoDB separate and isolate the locks for each project in this table? Or do I have to create multiple DynamoDB table for all my projects? Your guidance and thoughts on this would be appreciated.
I haven’t tried anything yet. Requirements gathering phase
